# Batch script to read and extract details from a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to copy a few files and folders to their respective destinations using a Windows batch script.

All the files and folders I am supposed to copy, are kept within a folder, `SOURCE`.

**Example**:

- folder: `C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A`
- file  : `C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A.txt`
- file  : `C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\B.txt`
- folder: `C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\ZZZ`

The destination paths of all the above are provided as text file contents, `destination.txt`.

**Content of destination.txt**:

```
C:\FinalDestination\D\A\...
C:\FinalDestination\N\A.txt
C:\FinalDestination\C\B.txt
C:\FinalDestination\U\ZZZ\...
```

Where three dots at the end signifies a directory, otherwise it's a file.

What I need to do in the above scenario is:

- Copy folder `A` from `SOURCE` to `C:\FinalDestination\D\`
- Copy file `A.txt` from `SOURCE` to `C:\FinalDestination\N\`
- Copy file `B.txt` from `SOURCE` to `C:\FinalDestination\C\`
- Copy folder `ZZZ` from `SOURCE` to `C:\FinalDestination\U\`

I don't know how to do it as I am pretty new to Windows command line.

I know `XCopy` is a command which can work for me, `xcopy source destination`, but I don't know how to extract the source and destination details.

Comment: Do you have any control over the design/layout of `destination.txt`? In my opinion using a sequence of two back slashes followed by three dots to signify a directory is absolutely crazy.

Comment: @compo: No, I don't have any control over it.

Comment: @compo: There are NO two back slashes followed by 3 dots.

Comment: @compo: There is only 1 back slash followed by 3 dots to represent a directory

Comment: I have corrected that in your question, _it appears that it was necessary for you in your original to use a back slash as an escape character for another_.

Comment: @compo: Thank You for restructuring my question properly.

Comment: Does anyone get anything which can help me? Please help me :(

Comment: @compo: Just wondering, if you have get any idea how to accomplish it ?

Comment: I thought you didn't have control over `destination.txt`. (Just saw your new question, where you appear to be using three dots only to identify directories, no back slash).

Comment: @Compo -- Thanks for noticing. I missed back-slash there. Updated my new question.

Comment: @Compo -- R u there?  Can u please suggest be a resolution for this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094912/how-to-redirect-output-of-a-batch-command-to-a-variables-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an unchanged `destination.txt` and your supplied data, the following may  help:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "sD=C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE"
Set "sF=destination.txt"

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%sF%"
) Do For %%B In ("%%~fA.") Do echo=XCopy/IY "%sD%\%%~nxB" "%%~dpA." 2>Nul
Pause
```

You need only modify the content of the variables at lines `3` and `4`

**Note**:

I have currently made it so that nothing is copied, just the commands output to your screen. If you are happy with the output remove `echo=` from line `7` and delete the content of line, `8`

Comment: It's working fine for files. But it's not for folders

Comment: What is the first line of output before you remove `echo=`

Comment: This is what I have got (without removing anything from your script):
Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A" "C:\FinalDestination\D\"
Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A.txt" "C:\FinalDestination\N\"
Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\B.txt" "C:\FinalDestination\C\"
Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\ZZZ" "C:\FinalDestination\U\"
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A" "C:\FinalDestination\D\"  -- This command is not working on comand prompt.

Comment: This is what shows when I run copy command on cmd: 

> Copy "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A" "C:\FinalDestination\D\"
C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A\*
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.

Comment: Good, I have now updated the script and used your suggested `XCopy` command, please retry.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It is working fine with files. But, unfortunately, it's still not working for copying folders.

Comment: XCopy/IY "C:\X\Y\Z\SOURCE\A" "C:\FinalDestination\D\A\."   ---- This command will show you error message - 0 File(s) copied

Comment: I have since posting tested this script on a Windows 7 machine. Both files and directories were copied as expected!